# Testing of a method with 2 transactions

Tags: java, junit, transactions, integration-testing

I would like to test method which have to create 2 transactions. But it seems that I can not access the session in scope of second transaction (another service method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`). This issue happens only in tests. The code example:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA implements A {

@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

@Transactional
public void m1() {
    //some actions with repositories
    serviceB.m2(id);
  }

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class ServiceB implements B {

@Autowired
private RepositoryA repositoryA;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void m2(Long id) {
    //some other actions
    m3(repositoryA.findOne(id).getSomething()); // NPE is thrown here
    //some other actions
  }
}
```

I get `NullPointerException` but only during tests (I am sure that object with such id exists in my test databese). When I try to get the same object in scope of first transaction, everything is working as expected

---

```
public class ServiceATest extends BaseTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/PATH_TO_A/" + ID).session(createSession(user)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()); 
   }
}
```

I get 404 HTTP code instead of 200 on reason of `NullPointerException`.

How to handle such case with multiple transactions during testing via JUnit?

Comment: Are you using SpringUnit or something? JUnit by itself is not able to handle Transactionannotations.